# Time Series Analysis / Modeling with auto_arima

Tags: python, time-series, forecasting, forecast

I recently dived into Time Series and was attempting at doing some data analysis and modeling. I'm using the following dataframe

```
             meantemp   humidity  wind_speed  meanpressure
date                                                      
2013-01-01  10.000000  84.500000    0.000000   1015.666667
2013-01-02   7.400000  92.000000    2.980000   1017.800000
2013-01-03   7.166667  87.000000    4.633333   1018.666667
2013-01-04   8.666667  71.333333    1.233333   1017.166667
2013-01-05   6.000000  86.833333    3.700000   1016.500000
...               ...        ...         ...           ...
2017-04-20  34.500000  27.500000    5.562500    998.625000
2017-04-21  34.250000  39.375000    6.962500    999.875000
2017-04-22  32.900000  40.900000    8.890000   1001.600000
2017-04-23  32.875000  27.500000    9.962500   1002.125000
2017-04-24  32.000000  27.142857   12.157143   1004.142857

[1575 rows x 4 columns]
```

describing the daily mean temperature, humidity and other stuff, but I'm focusing mostly on the 'meantemp' feature.

The plot looks like this:
[image: meantemp plot]

I had the intuition that this time series might be stationary, so I ran aan augmented Dickey-fuller test to check it..

```
dftest = adfuller(df['meantemp'])
dfout = pd.Series(dftest[0:4], index=['ADF','P-value', 'Usedlags', 'nobs'])
dfout
```

and I obtained

```
ADF           -2.377592
P-value        0.148161
Usedlags      10.000000
nobs        1564.000000
dtype: float64
```

So since p-value is >0.05 I can't assume it is actually stationary. At this point I ran an ETS

```
decomp = seasonal_decompose(df['meantemp'], period =12)
decomp.plot();
```

[image]

Now I already have some perplexities, since the seasonality component is pretty 'small' compared to the range of  the data..(should I ignore the seasonality?) Anyway then I use auto_arima to look for an appropriate model

```
auto_arima(df['meantemp'], seasonal=True, m=12).summary()
```

[image]

Now I have question.. What's the meaning in auto_arima returning back a SARIMAX model with just three components? Are those the 'order' components or 'seasonal' components? I'm pretty sure they are the 'order' components but then why doesn't it return back just an ARIMA one?
Also when I fit the model and predict on test data I obtain the following plot:
[image]

I also checked the RMSE and it's about 6.(numbers) compared to the mean of the whole data that is about 25... Does all of this make sense? Thank you!